# Controlling a buttons enabled state using 3 combobox selecteditem values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am developing a WPF application. I have 3 comboboxes. Each combobox has a List as source and there are 3 items : 1,2,3 in each combobox.
I have a button too. I want to disable the button if the user has selected the same value in atleast 2 of the comboboxes. 
Ie. If user selects 1 in first CB and 1 in second CB too, then disable the button. I have tried to achieve this using below code within  of button.
But it doesn’t work anyway.

```
<Button>
....
<Style> 
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="1" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB2, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="1" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB3, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="1" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Button>
```

Could you please suggest a better solution to do the same in `XAML` itself?

Comment: Are you using MVVM? If so, then you could use RelayCommand [like this](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/e5294f54-f460-8227-b228-ac63034b1294.htm) to be binded to button's command. Then command would be able to decide if button should be active, based on your ViewModel state.

Comment: Yes I am following MVVM pattern. I am already using `RelayCommand` to control button state like that. I am looking for some technique to control it in XAML itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `MultiValueConverter` to achieve this:

```
public class IsDistinctConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Distinct().Count() == values.Length;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The `Convert` method returns `true` if all items in the passed list are unique. In XAML you can use the converter like this:

```
<Button Content="My Button">
    <Button.Resources>
        <!-- You can move this Resource to another place without any problem -->
        <local:IsDistinctConverter x:Key="IsDistinctConverter"/>
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsDistinctConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="CB1"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="CB2"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="CB3"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

Comment: Any possibility to include it in <Button.Style> itself?

Comment: @Rennie You could try to set the `MultiBinding` as the Value inside a `Setter`. This should work. But you still need a reference to the `ComboBox`es. That's why I cannot see why you need to move the binding to a style.